# allowing user login useing data from different table

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to allow user login from two tables using one form, checking the first table if the user exist and if it does not exist it should check the other table else echo user does exist.  i have tried the following but its not working

```
<?php$username = $DBcon->real_escape_string($username);
$email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$get = "SELECT _userid, u_name, hemail, pass_word from five_thousand where hemail='$email' or u_name='$username' limit 1";
$get2 = "SELECT _userid, u_name, hemail, pass_word from ten_thousand where hemail='$email' or u_name='$username' limit 1";
 // for five thousand
 $drup = $DBcon->query($get);
 $row=$drup->fetch_array();

 // for ten thousand
 $drup2 = $DBcon->query($get2);
 $row2 = $drup2->fetch_array();

 if ($row['hemail'==1]) {
   if ($row['pass_word'] == $hash) {
    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
    header("Location: ../office.php");
}else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
   }
  }
 elseif ($row2['hemail']==1) {
   if ($row['pass_word'] == $hash) {
     $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
     header("Location: ../office.php");
  }else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
  }
 }else{
    echo "user does not exixt";
 }
$DBcon->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead

```
$username = $DBcon->real_escape_string( $username );
$email    = $DBcon->real_escape_string( $email );
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string( $password );
$hash     = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
$tables = array( 'five_thousand', 'ten_thousand' );

function getData( $table, $username, $email, $password, $DBcon ) {
    $query = "SELECT _userid, u_name, hemail, pass_word from $table where hemail='$email' or u_name='$username' limit 1";
    $drup  = $DBcon->query( $query );
    $row   = $drup->fetch_array();

    return $row['hemail'];
}

if ( $row = getData( 'five_thousand', $username, $email, $password, $DBcon )) {
    if ( $row['pass_word'] == $hash ) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header( "Location: ../office.php" );
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
            </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "user does not exixt";
}

if ( $row = getData( 'ten_thousand', $username, $email, $password, $DBcon )) {
    if ( $row['pass_word'] == $hash ) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header( "Location: ../office.php" );
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
            </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "user does not exixt";
}

$DBcon->close();
```